# Get all html form param name & value using jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a html form which contains elements like this

```
<input type="text" value="Val1" name="Name1"/>
<input type="text" value="Val2" name="Name2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Val3" name="Name3"/>
```

On server side, i use Jersey implementation to capture the form name and values. Is there a way to capture all of the above in a single Map like this

Name1 ==> Val1
Name2 ==> Val2
Name3 ==> Val3

I understand that using @FormParam, i can capture the form value in a variable . But i need to capture the form element name as well as value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give your method an argument of type `MultivaluedMap<String,String>`. Implementations are required to provide a `MessageBodyReader` for this type that responds to the media type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (§4.2.4 of the spec). So something like:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response foo(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm able to get all values using your suggestion. Just curious though, is it possible to capture all hidden form element in a separate Map and all text fields in a separate map?

Comment: @pra You would have to create your own `MessageBodyReader` for that.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - You can also use com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form instead of MultivaluedMap - it is essentially the same thing.