# How can I retrieve HttpServletRequest data while using Jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

I know that this is an easy one if I am not using Jersey and would use something like this:

```
Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
    String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Parameter Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getParameter(paramName)); 
}

params = request.getHeaderNames();
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
    String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Header Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getHeader(paramName));
}

params = request.getAttributeNames();
while(params.hasMoreElements()){
    String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Attribute Name - "+paramName+", Value - "+request.getAttribute(paramName));
}
```

I am also aware that I can do this and be done with it.

```
@FormParam("location") String location
```

But what if I do want to dump all the contents of the form submitted via POST?

The problem is that I am using Jersey as the implementation of JAX-RS and using the code above outputs this:

```
Attribute Name - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES, Value - org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.JaxrsRequestAttributes@11e035a
Attribute Name - org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger, Value - org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.TracingLogger$1@16e45c8
```

I am guessing that my data is contained here: JaxrsRequestAttributes I am not sure though.

I know I am missing something here. This isn't supposed to be difficult isn't it?

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested Sotirios,

This is the code get the dump of the form.

```
try {
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    int i;
    char c;
    while((i=is.read())!=-1)
        {
        // converts integer to character
        c=(char)i;

        // prints character
        System.out.print(c);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In order for this to work, I had to remove @FormParam in my parameter and leave out @Context HttpSerlvetRequest request.

Are there no other way to output this in a more elegant way with out the need to remove @FormParam? Maybe get the values from JaxrsRequestAttributes?

I tried to create a variable JaxrsRequestAttributes but it's a default class a can not access it directly.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to just dump all the contents submitted via POST. I can just add @FormParam but what if you don't know all the parameters and just want to know what other information is being sent.

Comment: Just read the request stream. Otherwise, use the first part of the code snippet you posted.

Comment: I can't. It says java.io.IOException: Stream closed.

Comment: Had to delete @FormParam and the exception went away

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I have updated the question. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: I believe `@FormParam` actually consumes the request input stream (and you can't consume it twice without some fancy `Filter` tricks). Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406921/get-all-html-form-param-name-value-using-jersey)?

Comment: You're right. I found that out too earlier before posting. Anyway, the link the you gave worked. Thanks! I am going to post answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Sotirios comment's, here's the answer:

Here's the method signature

```
public Response authenticateUser(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form)
```

---

```
Iterator<String> it = form.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String theKey = (String)it.next();
    System.out.println("Parameter Name - "+theKey+", Value - "+form.getFirst(theKey)); 
}
System.out.println(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

The HttpServletRequest can be accessed using :

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Isn't that enough?

Comment: It should be enough unless you are using Jersey as your JAX-RS implementation. Check out the third code block in my question. That's the result.